# measuring time across processes

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, benchmarking

I need to measure the communitcation latency between two processes on the same machine.The best way I have come up with is serializing `DateTime.UtcNow` (`DateTime.Now` seems to be so utterly slow that it extremely distorts my measurements) into the message and comparing it with the `DateTime.UtcNow` in the other process. Is this as good as it gets? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Beware of stopwatch: http://kristofverbiest.blogspot.com/2008/10/beware-of-stopwatch.html. I'd suggest `Process.TotalProcessorTime`.

Comment: Those warnings about Stopwatch are dreadfully overblown. It's due only to bugs in the BIOS or HAL on *some* older systems; it's not due to an intrinsic problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to measure and compare exact times between processes, you should use the Windows API function [`QueryPerformanceCounter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The values that it returns are synchronized between processes because it returns an internal processor value.

`Stopwatch` also uses `QueryPerformanceCounter()` in its implementation, but it doesn't expose the absolute values that are returned so you can't use it.

You will have to [use P/Invoke to call QueryPerformanceCounter()](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/QueryPerformanceCounter.html) but it's pretty easy.

The overhead of using P/Invoke is small. [From the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712982.aspx):

> PInvoke has an overhead of between 10 and 30 x86 instructions per call. In addition to this fixed cost, marshaling creates additional overhead. There is no marshaling cost between blittable types that have the same representation in managed and unmanaged code. For example, there is no cost to translate between int and Int32.

Since the value returned from `QueryPerformanceCounter()` is a long, there will be no additional marshaling cost from it, so you're left with an overhead of 10-30 instructions.

Also see [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2012/01/10/datetime-utcnow-is-generally-preferable-to-datetime-now.aspx) where it is stated that the resolution of UtcNow is around 10ms - which is pretty huge compared to the resolution of the performance counter. (Although I actually don't believe this is true for Windows 8; my measurements seem to show that UtcNow has a millisecond resolution).

Anyway, it is easy to demonstrate that P/Invoking QueryPerformanceCounter() has a higher resolution than using DateTime.UtcNow.

If you run a release build of the following code (run from OUTSIDE a debugger), you'll see that almost all the DateTime.UtcNow elapsed times are 0, whereas all the QueryPerformanceCounter() ones are nonzero.

This is because the resolution of DateTime.UtcNow is not high enough to measure the elapsed time of calling `Thread.Sleep(0)`, whereas `QueryPerformanceCounter()` is.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            {
                var t1 = DateTime.UtcNow;
                Thread.Sleep(0);
                var t2 = DateTime.UtcNow;

                Console.WriteLine("UtcNow elapsed = " + (t2-t1).Ticks);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            {
                long q1, q2;

                QueryPerformanceCounter(out q1);
                Thread.Sleep(0);
                QueryPerformanceCounter(out q2);

                Console.WriteLine("QPC elapsed = " + (q2-q1));
            }
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
        static extern bool QueryPerformanceCounter(out long lpPerformanceCount);
    }
}
```

Now I realise that it could be that the overhead of calling QueryPerformanceCounter() is so high that it is measuring how long it is taking to call, rather than how long `Thread.Sleep(0)` takes. We can eliminate that in two ways:

Firstly, we can modify the first loop as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    var t1 = DateTime.UtcNow;
    long dummy;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(out dummy);
    Thread.Sleep(0);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(out dummy);
    var t2 = DateTime.UtcNow;

    Console.WriteLine("UtcNow elapsed = " + (t2-t1).Ticks);
}
```

Now the UtcNow should be timing Thread.Sleep(0) *and* two calls to QueryPerformanceCounter(). But if you run it, you'll still see almost all the elapsed times being zero.

Secondly, we can time how long it takes to call QueryPerformanceCounter() a million times:

```
var t1 = DateTime.UtcNow;

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
{
    long dummy;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(out dummy);
}

var t2 = DateTime.UtcNow;
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed = " + (t2-t1).TotalMilliseconds);
```

On my system it takes around 32ms to call QueryPerformanceCounter() one million times.

Finally, we can time how long it takes to call DateTime.UtcNow one million times:

```
var t1 = DateTime.UtcNow;

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
{
    var dummy = DateTime.UtcNow;
}

var t2 = DateTime.UtcNow;
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed = " + (t2-t1).TotalMilliseconds);
```

On my system that takes around 10ms, which is around 3 times faster than calling QueryPerformanceCounter().

**In Summary**

So DateTime.UtcNow has lower overhead than P/Invoking QueryPerformanceCounter(), but it has much lower resolution.

So you pays your money and you takes your choice!

Comment: I wonder what the performance implications of using P/Invoke are. There will probably some marshalling each time I call it.

Comment: The overhead is tiny for that. And remember that the .Net framework is calling Windows API methods all the time.

Comment: The .NET framework is often also using `InternalCall`: for example `DateTime.UtcNow` uses `[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)] 
        internal static extern long GetSystemTimeAsFileTime();` I susect there is no P/Invoke, marshalling involved here.

Comment: @bitbonk True, and the overhead is such that (according to my measurements) it takes around 3 times longer to P/Invoke QueryPerformanceCounter() than it does to use DateTime.UtcNow. However, DateTime.UtcNow has much lower resolution. See my updated answer for details!